# How can I place a draggable element with the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to place a draggable HTML element automatically to your mouse position if you press a key on your keyboard?
So I want to make the ball move to my mouse position by pressing a single key.

This is the HTML code for the "ball" element.
So by pointing my mouse towards the goal, then by pressing a key, then the ball moves to the goal.

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Drag the ball.</p>

  <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/soccer-gate.svg" id="gate" class="droppable">

  <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball">

  <script>
    let currentDroppable = null;

    ball.onmousedown = function(event) {

      let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      ball.style.position = 'absolute';
      ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
      document.body.append(ball);

      moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

      function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
        ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
      }

      function onMouseMove(event) {
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

        ball.hidden = true;
        let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        ball.hidden = false;

        if (!elemBelow) return;

        let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.droppable');
        if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
          if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
            leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
          }
          currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
          if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
            // (maybe just left the droppable)
            enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
          }
        }
      }

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

      ball.onmouseup = function() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        ball.onmouseup = null;
      };

    };

    function enterDroppable(elem) {
      elem.style.background = 'pink';
    }

    function leaveDroppable(elem) {
      elem.style.background = '';
    }

    ball.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The event object passed to the callback of the `addEventListener()` method contains the coordinates of the user's click. Using absolute positioning, we can move our `invBall` element to the users cursor by setting the `top` and `left` style properties. The travel time is controlled by a CSS transition.

```js
const target = document.getElementById("invBall");

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  target.style.top = `${event.clientY}px`;
  target.style.left = `${event.clientX}px`;

})
```

```css
#invBall {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transition: .3s all ease-in-out
}
```

```html
<div id='invBall'>
```

Comment: Hey, my element just disappears when I click. I also edited my thread

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this? (Press space)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Drag the ball.</p>

  <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/soccer-gate.svg" id="gate" class="droppable">

  <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball">

  <script>
    let currentDroppable = null;

    ball.onmousedown = function(event) {

      let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      ball.style.position = 'absolute';
      ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
      document.body.append(ball);

      moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

      function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
        ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
      }

      function onMouseMove(event) {
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

        ball.hidden = true;
        let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        ball.hidden = false;

        if (!elemBelow) return;

        let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.droppable');
        if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
          if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
            leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
          }
          currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
          if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
            // (maybe just left the droppable)
            enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
          }
        }
      }

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

      ball.onmouseup = function() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        ball.onmouseup = null;
      };

    };

    function enterDroppable(elem) {
      elem.style.background = 'pink';
    }

    function leaveDroppable(elem) {
      elem.style.background = '';
    }

    ball.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };
    
    
    let x, y;   
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
      x = e.clientX;
      y = e.clientY;
    });

    document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
      if(e.code === 'Space') {
        ball.style.position = 'absolute';
        ball.style.top = `${y}px`;
        ball.style.left = `${x}px`;
      }     
    });
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```